# Maximum number of rows of CSV data in excel sheet

Tags: excel, csv

It is known that Excel sheets can display a maximum of 1 million rows. Is there any row limit for csv data, i.e. does Excel allow more than 1 million rows in csv format?

One more question: About this 1 million limitation; Can Excel hold more than 1 million data rows, even though it only displays a maximum of 1 million data rows?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

CSV files have no limit of rows you can add to them. Excel won't hold more that the 1 million lines of data if you import a CSV file having more lines.

Excel will actually ask you whether you want to proceed when importing more than 1 million data rows. It suggests to import the remaining data by using the text import wizard again - you will need to set the appropriate line offset.

Answer (score 13):

In my memory, excel (versions >= 2007) limits the power 2 of 20: 1.048.576 lines.

Csv is over to this boundary, like ordinary text file. So you will be care of the transfer between two formats.

Answer (score 3):

Using the **Excel Text import wizard** to import it if it is a text file, like a *CSV file*, is another option and can be done based on which row number to which row numbers you specify. See: [This link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857)