# Generating CSV/Excel file for 100 Million of records in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Requirement is like

We get the huge dataset from the database( > 1 billion records) and need to export it to the csv file or excel.

Currently implementation use CSV class CSV.generate

```
 CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << header
    @obj.find_each do |c|
     arr = [c.id,c.name,soon]
     csv << array
    end
 end
```

and sending the output to

```
Zip::File.open(file, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
        zip.get_output_stream("test.#{@format}") { |f| f.puts(convert_to_csv) }
      end
```

All this operation is done other delayed jobs
This works good when record is < 20,000 
But when rows starts growing it gets some memory issues.

What i was thinking is to chunk the record to pieces say 1 million rows into 50 files (1million/20000)(csv1.csv,csv2.csv,csv3.csv,csv4.csv,csv5.csv) and then concat them into single file or zip all files together(faster way)

Can any one give me idea how can I start on it.

Comment: can I ask where the csv data will be used? because I think Excel supports a max of 1 million rows, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757991/maximum-number-of-rows-of-csv-data-in-excel-sheet.  For this much data, you might better off with some kind of database dump format.

Comment: One of the first things I would consider in this case is to get rid of unnecessary ORM overhead and use lower level queries to DB - there is not that much point in instantiating of billion of AR entities just to fetch 3 properties from them - using raw dataset will reduce memory usage and increase performance notably...

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `1million/20000` is 50, not 5 btw. Also, [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Didnt know about that feature, thanks! Similar one but for postgres https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the source for CSV.generate gives me the impression that the csv data is kept in memory while the contents are being accumulated.  That seems like a good target for optimization, especially if you see that memory is scaling linearly with the data set.  Since your data is pretty simple, could you skip CSV and go directly to File instead?  You'd have a bit more control about when data was flushed out to disk.

```
File.open("my.csv") do |file|
  file.puts '"ID","Name","Soon"'
  @obj.find_each do |c|
    file.puts "\"#{c.id}\",\"#{c.name}\",\"#{c.soon}\""
    # flush if necessary
  end
end
```

You'd need to write to disk and then zip the results later with this approach.

Comment: The bottleneck is obviously an `ActiveRecord`, not CSV.

Answer (score 2):

Write to the CSV in chunks and `find_in_batches` and `pluck`. Something like:

```
Model.pluck(:id, :name, ...).find_in_batches(10_000) do |ary|
  CSV.open("tmp.csv", "ab") do |csv|
    csv << ary.map{|a| a.join ','}.join("\n")
  end
end
```

Comment: the OP is using find_each which, I’m sure you know, uses find_in_batches and then iterates over the batches and yields the results. The point of find_each is precisely avoiding memory issues and I’ve used it quite successfully for larger data sets tha. The OP suggests are problematic.  It’s less “obviously ActiveRecord” than you simply assert.

Comment: How can this improve the performance as find_each also iterate in batches (:1000)?

Comment: Because the CSV falls out of scope and does not use a large amount of memory. In the OP's example, the entire CSV is held in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend whether

```
     arr = [c.id,c.name,soon]
```

needs to be calculated in Ruby, or you would be able to rewrite it in SQL.

- If you have to keep it in Ruby, you can try to avoid the ActiveRecord overhead and use a [raw query](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute) instead. You'd probably have to implement the chunk wise processing by yourself
- Otherwise, you could check out some database native tool for CSV export. E.g., for MySQL that would be something like `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` or [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html)